# SQL Server - High Performance Record Comparison

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, query-performance

**Scenario** : I have a collection of records to be inserted/updated into a table. Each record before getting inserted/updated in the table must be checked with the other rows in the table so as to find whether the same record already exists.

**Currently used logic** : Used the concept of cursor in an SQL server stored procedure to compare each record with every other record in the table before insertion/updation.

**Limitations** : As the number of records increases in the target table, performance is considerably decreased.

Can I get a better solution than what I have used?

Comment: Without looking at code it would not be good to suggest but consider changing cursor to set based logic. Probably while loop would be correct replacement.

Comment: Why not use a unique constraint for integrity and handle the violations in error handling (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/handling-constraint-violations-and-errors-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Show us your table definitions and code. Without it we're guessing.

Comment: But, in general, for high-performance you'll do better to switch to set-based processing rather than row-by-row, aka slow-by-slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at using the Merge command, this was introduced in SQL Server 2008 and does an update or insert based on your matching criteria.

I use this for merging XML quite a lot and it seems very efficient.

```
MERGE [Database] AS TargetTABLE
USING (SELECT @Var1 AS [Value1]
    @Var2 AS [Value2], 
    @Var3 AS [Value3]) AS SourceTABLE
ON TargetTABLE.[id] = SourceTABLE.[Value1]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TargetTABLE.[Value2] = SourceTABLE.[Value2],
        TargetTABLE.[Value3] = SourceTABLE.[Value3]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        [id], 
        [Value1],
        [Value2],
        [Value3])
    VALUES (
        SourceTABLE.[Value1], 
        SourceTABLE.[Value2],
        SourceTABLE.[Value3]
    );
```

[Merge Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx)